# R: How to have a violin plot, box-percentile plot that takes into account sample size?

Tags: r, plot, kernel-density, density-plot

To use a simple example, let's say:

```
A = rnorm(10)
B = rnorm(100)
C = rnorm(500)

library(vioplot)
vioplot(A,B,C)
```

My question is thus how to create such a graph that takes into account the sample size. 'C' has a much higher sample size than 'A', is there a way where the violin plot for 'C' can show a "bigger" violin than 'A'? Thus this would be density distribution that goes across the three classes I suppose, thus even though the entire distribution shape of 'A' and 'C' may be equal, rather than showing identical images they show 'A' being of smaller shape stature than 'C' and 'B' as well due to its smaller sample size.

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible by having a look at [**How to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for us to help you. Thank you.

Comment: There is a good answer and discussion of this over on [CrossValidated][1]


  [1]: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13555/how-to-scale-violin-plots-for-comparisons

Comment: Thanks Arun, I've edited my question in accordance with what you mentioned.

Comment: Hi Stedy, thanks for the link, I would say the Weighted Areas is what I'm looking for. Do you happen to know the code for that since it doesn't appear to be listed on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate that vioplot doesn't accept vectors for some of its parameters. Here's a workaround. The helpful features in `vioplot()` for this workaround are the `at` and `wex` parameters along with `add=T`. Basically plot each violin individually with the parameters that shape them the way you want. You may need to make adjustments to the way you scale the sample size for use with `wex`.

```
n<-c(100,1000)
size<-scale(sqrt(n),center=F)

x1<-rnorm(n[1])
x2<-rnorm(n[2])

#initialize an empty plot
plot(0:3,rep(0,4),type='l',xlim=c(0,3),ylim=c(-4,4),ylab="",xlab="",xaxt="n",lty=3)

# fill in the violins at specific x locations using the `wex` parameter for size
vioplot(x1,at=1,wex=size[1],add=T,col="darkgray")
vioplot(x2,at=2,wex=size[2],add=T,col="darkgray")
axis(1,at=1:2,labels=c("Mon","Tues"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ndoogan, definitely something I should be able to incorporate into my data.

Answer (score 1):

Sizes will not be different because violin plot is a combination of boxplot and density/probability plot.

Here is short example:

```
library(ggplot2)
```

a) same size

```
df.ex<-data.frame(G=c(rep('A',100),rep('B',100)),Y=c(rnorm(100),rnorm(100)))
ggplot(data=df.ex,aes(x=G,y=Y)) + geom_violin()
```

b) different size

```
df.ex<-data.frame(G=c(rep('A',100),rep('B',1000)),Y=c(rnorm(100),rnorm(1000)))
ggplot(data=df.ex,aes(x=G,y=Y)) + geom_violin()
```

You can combine it with `geom_jitter` that will show you how many points is there:

```
 ggplot(data=df.ex,aes(x=G,y=Y)) + geom_jitter() + geom_violin()
```

Comment: Thanks Miciej, the info about implementing geom_jitter was very helpful. There was a link included in one of the comments above from another user that seems quite interesting as well.